# Wordpress : hide Submenus, but show active submenu (3 tier)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, menu

I've searched up and down the internet and cannot find an answer that fits my specific needs for this.  I'd really appreciate some help.

I've set up a menu in Wordpress, and have set some Jquery code to hide the .sub-menu so that only the top level menu items show.  On click, the second tier opens, and clicking on one of those will open the third tier.  Only the third tier are actually URL links, the others are just #.

That all works lovely. The problem is, when the user clicks on a third-tier link, and is taken to the relevant page, I want THAT tier to stay open on the new page.

I've managed to assign a .active class to the li within the ul for the open page, but I can't seem to target it in Jquery to force it to show the sub-menu but only for the ul/li that has the .active class...

Any ideas?

My JQuery:

```
$('.sub-menu').hide(); //Hide children by default
$('li a').click(function(){

$(this).siblings('.sub-menu').slideToggle('slow');
}
```

How do I target the correct navigation tier to keep that one open when viewing that page?

Comment: I'm thinking I wrap an if statement around the "$('.sub-menu').hide();" so only hide that particular .sub-menu if it's children don't have the .active class?

Comment: You're loading a new page...unless you have some method of transferring information to the new page from the old page nothing can & will happen.

Comment: Hi Paulie, Thanks for the comment.  Yes I'm loading a new page (the Jquery is in the header.php).  The page in the navigation that is currently being viewed has a .active class assigned to it, but the 3 tier nav is what's confusing me because I can't check if the sub-menu has a .active class and hide that particular sub-menu only if it doens't.

Comment: I saw this recently - "You would use a parameter with like GET or POST and would have to set the menu active programmatically on each load depending on that parameter. Either that or you load your new page content with AJAX and retain the menu, header, footer and whatever you like"